# TCP socket dosen't seems to connect after a promise, in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, logstash

I have a program that reads, manipulates and tries to send a file via tcp to another program (logstash, of the elastic stack). Logstash is listening on the tcp port before this program runs.

I create a socket after a chain of promisess that are all resolved, something like so:

```
const net = reqire('net')
foo ()=>{
let firstPromise = new Promise(...resolve())
firstPromise.then(()=>{
return new Promise(....resolve(file))
}).then((someFile)=>{
    console.log('inside the connections stuff')
    let new_client = new net.Socket()
    new_client.connect(port,host,function(){
       conslog.log('connected')
       new_client.write(someFile)
       new_client.destroy()
    })
})
}
foo()
```

When I run it, everything seems to work fine, and I see the message that logs that the program got inside to the connection part. The thing is - there is no indication that any connection was made - no log message that alerts me, nothing.

I used this syntax after this example:
https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757
but any other TCP connection syntax yielded the same result - net.connect, net.creatconnection, etc.

My questions are:

1. Why there seems that no connection was made?
2. I saw (in other program I wrote) that logstash recived the file only when the connection was killed after client.write(), i.e as long as I just wrote "client.write()" its seems as logstash waited for more transmissions and didn't show the file recieved, so I added new_client.destroy(). Was it the right thing to do? If I send a big file via tcp, how the reciever knows whene the transmission is over (for example, in order to seperate the info from future info from a differant file?) This is relevat for my because I run foo() for many files, one after another.
3. It didn't seem to connect even after I put the connection in a promise of its self (meaning it shouldn't continue until I resolved it with the msg the connection was made) - but still, it just skipped on the conncetion. Why is this happening?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: This might not be useful but during my introduction to logstash I ran into some similar problems. Sending data over TCP and only getting the message when the connection was killed. If I remember well the size of the logs was the source of the problem. Too big logs lines (we had screenshots in the data) Try some basic small text messages for testing (if you didn't do this before).

Comment: @MrSimple: Thank you for the answer, but my problem is that node dosen't try to execute the socket connection